# Assistance with Apache Wildcard catchall

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, dnsmasq

OS: Ubuntu 13.10

I followed this article [Setting up a wildcard Apache virtual host + a wildcard DNS](http://www.brunodbo.ca/blog/2013/04/setting-up-wildcard-apache-virtual-host-wildcard-dns) to set up a wildcard virtual host so I don't need to hack hosts files etc every time I set up a new project.

I am getting 403 errors when trying to open a simple index.html file.

Error from `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

> [Mon Mar 24 23:03:48.919858 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 3728] [client 127.0.0.1:46408] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/moore/Workspace/test/public/favicon.ico

Here is my apache config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias localhost *.dev #wildcard catch all
  VirtualDocumentRoot /home/moore/Workspace/%1/public
  UseCanonicalName Off
  <Directory "home/moore/Workspace">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 <Directory "home/moore/Workspace">
```

with

```
 <Directory "/home/moore/Workspace">
```